# Scaling problem in some applications after 20.04 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, wine, fonts, vnc, scaling

After upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 lts to 20.04 lts I am finding that ***some*** applications (but not all) the appearance is very tiny and will not scale with adjustments to scaling in settings. Attached is a partial screen shot showing the issue with VNC Viewer. Interestingly, when I establish a remote desktop connection with this application, the remote desktop image will scale proportionally with the window but the controls do not. They remain very small. I am having the same issue with an application that I run in Wine.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[Example screen shot showing tiny fonts, images, etc. in VNC Viewer window compared with header font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMl5t.png)

Comment: I did install gnome tweaks to achieve fractional scaling in 18.04 before I upgraded to 20.04. I did not try uninstalling tweaks but turning off changes in tweaks does not solve the issue. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling VNC Viewer and my app in Wine but that did not solve the issue.

Comment: Does [this bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1870736) apply?

Comment: It does not seem that bug applies. I have no Nvidia graphics. System is a Dell XPS 13 9300.